# Creating QR Code in React and Uploading that to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, qr-code, mern

I am working on a MERN project where I need to create a qr code using React and upload that to firebase.

I know how to create QR Code in React. Separate packages are there to do it.

And I also know how to upload images and files(basically media files) to firebase.

But the files need to be downloaded into our local system to get uploaded to the firebase.

So how to link the creation of the qr code and uploading that to the firebase?

Answer (score 2):

As QR-Codes resolves to strings, I would just send the string to the server, then on the client I would render it to a QR-Code:

```js
// client that creates qr-code data
function Form() {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const dataStr = 'whatever you want the qr-code to resolve to'
    fetch('https://firebase-whatever/api/qr-code/ab123', {method: 'POST', body: dataStr})
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {/* your form fields... */}
    </form>
}


// another client that renders qr-code from the data in the server
import QRCode from 'qrcode' // see https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode

function ShowQrCode({id}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQrCode = async (id) => {
      const res = await fetch('https://firebase-whatever/api/qr-code/ab123')
      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

      QRCode.toCanvas(canvas, res.body, function (error) {
        if (error) console.error(error)
        console.log('success!');
      })
    }
    
    fetchQrCode(id);
  })
  
  return <canvas id="canvas" />
}
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: alternatively, you could generate the qrcode as base64 and send that to the server.
see https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode docs